# How to press 'y' in popup cofirmation window by GEB?

Tags: groovy, geb

I'm trying to automate file download function.
When I click a link of PDF, download confirmation window will pop up.
How to write geb code to click Y in (Y/N) selection in popup window by GEB script?

Answer (score 0):

Using withConfirm(true) will bypass the confirm box by clicking okay.
$() is the Jquery element for the button responsible for Dialog box.
.click() makes a click

```
withConfirm(true) { $("Element responsible for download").click() }
```